# JFrame subclass and ActionListener interface implementation

Tags: java, programming-languages

Why is `extends JFrame implements ActionListener` a bad design decision?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: No, it is a language specific question for a language I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple points:

- Extending a `JFrame` is probably a wrong approach
- Implementing an `ActionListener` on an `JFrame` probably will lead to non-OOP code.

**Wrong Approach?**

If the idea is that an GUI application is being made, then, one is not making an extension of a `JFrame`, but actually writing an application.

Therefore, the `JFrame` would be part of an application, not the application itself. Hence, the `JFrame` should be an object in the class.

**Implementing an `ActionListener` on an `JFrame` probably will lead to non-OOP code**

Consider the following case -- as the GUI application is starting to get large, and we're starting to add lots of buttons and menus which give rise to `ActionEvent`s.

If the `JFrame` itself were to get the events, then what would the `actionPerformed` method look like?

Probably something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object source = e.getSource();

  // Find out which component fired the event
  if (source == masterButton) {
    // ... do something
  } else if (source == anotherButton) {
    // ... do something else
  } else if (...)
    // ... and so on ...
  } else if (...)
    // ... and so on ...
  }
}
```

Yikes.

We're going to start getting code that's tightly coupled to all the components in the application, and maintainability will be out the window in no time.

---

If, for example, the GUI application had instances of `ActionLister`s which responded to each component, then we'd be able to break up the actions and the coupling of the `actionPerformed` method with all the components in the GUI.

For example:

```
JButton masterButton = new JButton();
masterButton.addActionListener(new MasterButtonActionListener());

JButton anotherButton = new JButton();
anotherButton.addActionListener(new AnotherButtonActionListener());
```

This way, there will be `ActionListeners` for each button which presumably have different functionality. The responsibility of the `MasterButtonActionListener` would be to handle events from the `masterButton` -- it doesn't have to know about other buttons in the application.

Also, this would promote reusability of the components in other applications or other part of the application without having to copy-and=paste parts of the monolithic `if-else` statement in the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: Coolbird Thanks for taking the time to post such a detailed explanation.

Comment: It would be better to create Action objects rather than have multiple ActionListeners. Take a look at the Java Tutorial on How to Use Actions: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Answer (score 1):

If you read Effective Java, item 16 states:

> "**Favor composition over inheritence**"

.  Read the explanation given [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=favor+composition+over+inheritance+effective+java&source=bl&ots=yXLjKit6M4&sig=VyGQyzDUYewB1Ku-txuoqzYeiBM&hl=en&ei=_aMkTfTjH4masAOu_JiSAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Hello Amir, could you possibly phrase this is a simpler way? I am very rusty with my JAVA syntax - so one inherits from the other - but this is a bad idea because one is a 'ordinary concrete class'.

Comment: Hi JHarley - what he is saying there about not inheriting from an ordinary concrete class from another package is simply that changes in that class will directly impact yours.  If you kept a reference to a JFrame, you could encapsulate it's behaivor - with sublcassing, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is a bad design .. Because, you mix controller code with view.. if you want to follow mvc pattern, you should not mix them..

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, A `JFrame` generally doesn't receive actions.  Its child objects would be the benefactors of an `ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

A better and more OO approach would be to have separate Action objects. This allows you to separate functionality and state from a component. It makes your code reusable because you can use the same action on a button as well as menu item, for instance.

Example:

```
class ExitAction extends AbstractAction{    
    public ExitAction(){
        super("Exit");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Exiting");
    }
}

JButton exitButton = new JButton(new ExitAction());
```

Take a look at [**How to Use Actions**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) in the Java Tutorial: